# visual studio WSL vi file.json

Tags: json, yaml

I'm using ubuntu extension in Visual Studio .(WSL).

When I open vi file, like `vi file.json` or `vi file.yml`, and trying to paste code file in it, `wsl` automatically insert the indentation and moving the rows to right.

[image]

copied Json file pasted into vi file of ubuntu or visual studio WSL gave same result of indentation.

Does anyone have an idea how to paste the codes or other file as it is?

Answer (score 0):

It should work with the old fashion CTRL+C (copy) and CTRL+V(paste) from within the Visual Studio Code terminal. If not you could always try vi commands [https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-copy-cut-paste-in-vim/#:~:text=Copy%2C%20Cut%2C%20and%20Paste%20in%20Visual%20Mode.%201,the%20text%20is%20selected%20by%20rectangle%20blocks.%20](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-copy-cut-paste-in-vim/#:%7E:text=Copy%2C%20Cut%2C%20and%20Paste%20in%20Visual%20Mode.%201,the%20text%20is%20selected%20by%20rectangle%20blocks.%20)

[here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obYrD.png)